# find difference in images

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a simple find the difference game in android by using touch coordinates of each difference but when I note down the coordinates in one device then it's working fine. and when I use some other device those coordinates aren't there. so is there any way in which I can work this out

here's some of the code:

```
image1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @SuppressLint({"ClickableViewAccessibility", "UseCompatLoadingForDrawables"})
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int X =(int) event.getX();
                int Y =(int) event.getY();
                String msg = "Coordinates are " + X + "and" + Y;
                int eventAction = event.getAction();
                if(eventAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    int x = (int) event.getX();
                    int y = (int) event.getY();
                    if(checkPoint(X,Y) == true){
                        
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,msg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             
                    }

private boolean checkPoint(int x, int y) {
        int touchX = (int) x;
        int touchY = y;       
       float centerX = 950, centerY = 600;
        float radius = 100;
        if (Math.pow(centerX-touchX , 2)
                + Math.pow(centerY-touchY , 2) < Math.pow(radius, 2))
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"points inside circe",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"points outside circle",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }      
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify "those coordinates aren't there". Are they 0, isn't `onTouch()` called or what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff, I have two images from which I was taking the coordinate of difference by myself and then checking if the user touches around those coordinate but this is only working of one device only. so I want a logic from which I can get various differences between images